# I want to display the data as percentages on the x-axis in plotly (python)

Tags: python, plotly-python

I want to display the data on x-axis as a percentage.

I tried different methods including the #tickformat method, but wasn't able to successfully get the required output.

```
trace4 = go.Bar(
    y=[''],
    x=[5731],
    name='Other(Used/Available)',
    text = ("5731"),
    textposition = 'inside',
    orientation = 'h',
    marker = dict(
        color = 'rgba(210, 105, 30, 0.6)',
        line = dict(
            color = 'rgba(210, 105, 30, 1.0)',
            width = 3)
    )
)
data = [trace1, trace2, trace3, trace4]
layout = go.Layout(
    autosize=False,
    width=800,
    height=275,
    barmode='stack',
    xaxis=dict(tickformat="%")
)

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
py.iplot(fig, filename='marker-h-bar')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, I figured this out myself. I calculated the total, and then calculated the percentage that way. After that, just used `xaxis=dict(ticksuffix="%")` to assign the "%" symbol.

```
l = []

for i in rows2:
    l.append(list(i))

schema = [i[0] for i in l]

nos = [i[1] for i in l]

nos = [int(x) for x in nos]

i = 0
t = 0
while i < len(nos):
    t += nos[i]
    i += 1

P = [float(x/t*100) for x in nos]

trace1 = go.Bar(
    y=[''],
    x=[P[0]], 
    name = (f"{schema[0]}"),
    text = (f"{nos[0]}"),
    textposition = 'auto',
    orientation = 'h',
    marker = dict(
        color = 'rgba(103, 240, 160, 0.75)',
        line = dict(
            color = '#43BD78',
            width = 3)
    )
)
trace2 = go.Bar(
    y=[''],
    x=[P[1]],
    name=(f"{schema[1]}"),
    text = (f"{nos[1]}"),
    textposition = 'auto',
    orientation = 'h',
    marker = dict(
        color = 'rgba(255, 172, 188, 0.75)',
        line = dict(
            color = '#E67188',
            width = 3)
    )
)
trace3 = go.Bar(
    y=[''],
    x=[P[2]],
    name=(f"{schema[2]}"),
    text = (f"{nos[2]}"),
    textposition = 'auto',
    orientation = 'h',
    marker = dict(
        color = 'rgba(177, 193, 216, 1.0)',
        line = dict(
            color = '#82A1D0',
            width = 3)
    )
)
trace4 = go.Bar(
    y=[''],
    x=[P[3]],
    name=(f"{schema[3]}"),
    text = (f"{nos[3]}"),
    textposition = 'auto',
    orientation = 'h',
    marker = dict(
        color = 'rgba(250, 184, 126, 0.75)',
        line = dict(
            color = '#DF8E47',
            width = 3)
    )
)
trace5 = go.Bar(
    y=[''],
    x=[P[4]],
    name=(f"{schema[4]}"),
    text = (f"{nos[4]}"),
    textposition = 'inside',
    orientation = 'h',
    marker = dict(
        color = '#C8A8CD',
        line = dict(
            color = '#9C7DA1',
            width = 3)
    )
)
data = [trace1, trace2, trace3, trace4, trace5]
layout = go.Layout(
    autosize=False,
    width=700,
    height=110,
    barmode='stack',
    xaxis=dict(ticksuffix="%"),
    legend=dict(
        orientation="h", 
        x=0.05, 
        y=-0.27,
        font=dict(
            size=10.5
        )
    ),
    margin=go.layout.Margin(
        l=60,
        r=60,
        b=0,
        t=0,
        pad=0
    )
)

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
py.iplot(fig, filename='marker-h-bar')
```